# Indexing inside of lm() R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm writing a `for` loop that returns `jtools` `effect_plot`s for each individual regressor in a dataframe against the dependent variable "Score".

This code returns the correct result for a single iteration with the regressor `data$Fab`:

```
model <- lm(Score~Fab, data=data)
effect_plot(model, pred = Fab, data=data)
```

This is what I attempted in order to loop through all of the columns of `data`:

```
for (i in colnames(data)){
model <- lm(Score~i, data=data)
effect_plot(model, pred = i, data=data)
}
```

This returns a "variable lengths differ" error, which was not present in my single-regressor attempt. A few things I tried were using `data[[i]]` in place of i, and `noquote(i)` in place of i, neither of which worked. Any advice on how to properly reference the columns of my dataframe inside of a for loop, or a more effective method, is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the formula with `paste` or `reformulate` in the `lm` and use `!!` to pass an object as per the `?effect_plot`

> pred - The name of the predictor variable involved in the interaction. This can be a bare name or string. Note that it is evaluated using rlang, so programmers can use the !! syntax to pass variables instead of the verbatim names.

```
for (i in colnames(data)){
   model <- lm(reformulate(i, response = "Score'), data=data)
   # // or using paste
   # model <- lm(as.formula(paste0('Score~', i)), date = data)
   jtools::effect_plot(model, pred = !!i, data=data)
}
```

EDIT: From OP's comments about `effect_plot`

Comment: Thanks! That worked for lm(), seems like it's still having trouble with effect_plot(), which is trying to pass the letter "i" as a predictor instead of whatever column name "i" represents.

EDIT -- looks like effect_plot() requires "!!i" in order to use it as a variable.

Comment: @Scoops you are right.  I was checking the documentation